# PhpStorm TODO feature in opened remote file

Tags: phpstorm, todo

TODO list not displayed for opened remote file. Only for local.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately remote files are not indexed therefore there's no advanced completion or TODO matching for remote files - you need to fetch it to the local side in order to get the TODO information displayed properly.